# Convert a custom object array to System.Array in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have an array of custom objects. MyCustomArr[]. I want to convert this to System.Array so that I can pass it to a method that accepts only System.Array. The signature of the method is:

```
public void Load(Array param1, string param2)
{

}
```

Comment: You have not stated what you tried, and what the results of those attempts were.  Did you get any compile errors? run-time exceptions? other helpful information.  I think there is more to your question than you wrote.  But unless you provide detailed, helpful information, no one here can do much for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No conversion is needed for that as far as I know. You can simply go ahead and pass your array to the method. The following code works out well:

```
MyClass[] myClassArray = new MyClass[2];
myClassArray[0] = new MyClass();
myClassArray[1] = new MyClass();
Load(myClassArray, "some text");
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do with the array?  The code below builds and runs, so I'm not sure where your problem lies:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public class MyObject 
    {
    }

    public static void RunSnippet()
    {
        MyObject[] objects = new MyObject[5];
        Test(objects);  
    }

    private static void Test(System.Array obj)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Count: " + obj.Length.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to cast it, but I think this will be done implicitly for you.

```
System.Array array = (System.Array)(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```